# fncychap not applied to a chapter

Tags: fncychap

I'm using `fncychap` package with the option

```
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
```

I wouldn't apply it to only the first chapter and instead apply to all the next chapter. How can I do? I mean I have the part of the acknowledgements created using

```
\chapter*{}
```

and after that I start the first chapter of my book

```
\chapter{first chapter}
```

I wouldn't have fancy in `\chapter*{}`

Comment: Why should a chapter be different from the others?

Comment: Because it is not a really chapter...it is the part of the acknoledgements

Comment: So what? If it's a chapter treat it like a chapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want different formatting for an "Acknowledgments" section, just define it as you like; for instance

```
\newcommand{\acknowledgments}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \vspace*{0pt}% the margin from the top
  \phantomsection % if you use hyperref
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\acknowledgmentsname} % if you want it in the TOC
  {\centering\bfseries\Large \acknowledgmentsname\par}
  \vspace*{\bigskipamount}% vertical space between title and text
  \noindent\ignorespaces % omit this line if you want to indent the first paragraph
}

\newcommand{\acknowledgmentsname}{Acknowledgments} % or whatever
% If babel is loaded, use also the following for the language
% in which the section is written; for instance
% \addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\acknowledgmentsname}{Ringraziamenti}}
```

Then at the appropriate spot, issue

```
\acknowledgments
```

Change the formatting as you please. But, in my opinion, this should be a chapter like all the others (possibly not using `fncychap`, but this is personal opinion).